# Consulta SQL en pgAdmin - Votos

Tags: sql, pgadmin

Tengo la siguiente base de datos en pgAdmin, con inserts de prueba:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PARTIDO, MUNICIPIO, PRESENTARSE, COLEGIO, MESA, CENSO, ESVOTADO CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PARTIDO (
    siglas VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    direccion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MUNICIPIO (
    nombre VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    poblacion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    votostotales INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRESENTARSE (
    siglas VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES PARTIDO(siglas) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) REFERENCES MUNICIPIO(nombre) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (siglas,nombre));

    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COLEGIO (
    ndistrito INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL REFERENCES MUNICIPIO(nombre) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    preside VARCHAR(9) );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MESA (
    ndistrito INTEGER REFERENCES COLEGIO(ndistrito) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    numero INTEGER,
    nvotosnulos INTEGER,
    nvotosblanco INTEGER,
    preside VARCHAR(9),
    PRIMARY KEY (ndistrito,numero));
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CENSO (
    dni VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    votaen_ndist INTEGER NOT NULL,
    votaen_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    compone_ndist INTEGER, 
    compone_num INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (votaen_ndist,votaen_num) REFERENCES MESA(ndistrito,numero),
    FOREIGN KEY (compone_ndist,compone_num) REFERENCES MESA(ndistrito,numero) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL);


ALTER TABLE COLEGIO 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (preside) REFERENCES CENSO(dni) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE MESA 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (preside) REFERENCES CENSO(dni) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ESVOTADO (
    ndistrito INTEGER,
    numero INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (ndistrito,numero) REFERENCES MESA(ndistrito,numero) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    siglas VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES PARTIDO(siglas) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    nvotos INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ndistrito,numero,siglas));


INSERT INTO PARTIDO VALUES 
    ('p1','part1','s1'),
    ('p2','part2','s2'),
    ('p3','part3','s3');

INSERT INTO MUNICIPIO VALUES 
    ('m1','local1',null),
    ('m2','local2',null),
    ('m3','local3',null);

INSERT INTO PRESENTARSE VALUES 
    ('p1','m1'),
    ('p2','m1'),
    ('p3','m1'),
    ('p1','m2'),
    ('p2','m2'),
    ('p3','m2'),
    ('p1','m3'),
    ('p2','m3'),
    ('p3','m3');

INSERT INTO COLEGIO VALUES 
    (1,'m1', NULL),
    (2,'m1', NULL),
    (3,'m2', NULL),
    (4,'m3', NULL);

INSERT INTO MESA VALUES 
    (1,1, NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (1,2, NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (2,1, NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (2,2, NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (3,1, NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (3,2, NULL,NULL,NULL);

INSERT INTO CENSO VALUES 
    ('CENSO1','CENSO1p',1,1,1, 1),
    ('CENSO2','CENSO2',1,1,1, 1),
    ('CENSO3','CENSO3',1,1,1, 1),
    ('CENSO4','CENSO4',1,1,1, 1),
    ('CENSO5','CENSO5',1,1,1, 1),
    ('CENSO6','CENSO6',1,1,NULL, NULL),
    ('CENSO7','CENSO7',1,1,NULL, NULL),
    ('CENSO8','CENSO8',1,2,1, 2),
    ('CENSO9','CENSO9',1,2,1, 2),
    ('CENSO10','CENSO10',1,2,1, 2),
    ('CENSO11','CENSO11',1,2,1, 2),
    ('CENSO12','CENSO12',1,2,1, 2),
    ('CENSO13','CENSO13',1,2,NULL, NULL),
    ('CENSO14','CENSO14',1,2,NULL, NULL),
    ('CENSO15','CENSO15',2,1,NULL, NULL),
    ('CENSO16','CENSO16',2,2,NULL, NULL),
    ('CENSO17','CENSO17',3,1,NULL, NULL),
    ('CENSO18','CENSO18',3,2,NULL, NULL);
    

WITH MYDATA(ndistrito,numero,preside) AS (
    VALUES
        (1,1,'CENSO1'),
        (1,2,'CENSO8'))
UPDATE MESA e SET preside=m.preside
    FROM MYDATA m WHERE m.ndistrito=e.ndistrito and m.numero=e.numero;
    
INSERT INTO ESVOTADO VALUES
    (1,1,'p1',2),
    (1,1,'p2',1),
    (1,1,'p3',3),
    (1,2,'p1',1),
    (1,2,'p2',2),
    (1,2,'p3',3);
```

Necesito una consulta que me retorne los votos y siglas (las dos columnas) de los partidos cuyo número de votos en el municipio 'm1' es igual al número de votos nulos más el número de votos en blanco en ese mismo municipio. He pensado en una reunión entre COLEGIO y MESA, con una una subconsulta correlacionada con una agrupación que diera el total de sumar todos los votos nulos y en blanco, pero estoy un poco atascada.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Pasa insert intos o el .bak

Comment: Ya está editado